# groovy "...".execute() works on windows but fails on linux

Tags: linux, groovy

while this line works fine on windows on my linux box it returns exit code 1.

```
"gnuplot -e \"set output '${imageFile.toString()}'; filename='${dataFile.toString()}'; ${args}\" \"${plotFile.toString()}\"".execute()
```

But if I execute just this from the terminal everything works.

```
gnuplot -e "set output '/tmp/hrp-current.jpg'; filename='/tmp/a731265b-3736-4bb9-acf4-b92c1a09b999.csv'; " "/tmp/hrp/build/groovy/../gnuplot/hrp-current.gnuplot"
```

What am I missing here? It somehow has to do with the fact that gnuplot writes to a file because `some_command > some.file" also fails on linux with exit code 1 while it would work fine on windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it is some file writing issue so I need gnuplot to pipe its outout to stdout and then consume it from my groovy script where I read the outputstream and then save it to a file:

```
def out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
def err = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
process.waitForProcessOutput(out, err)
```

Answer (score 1):

`.execute()` on a String just splits on whitespace.  You also don't need to quote the params for execution (you need to that for the shell).  So execute an list of params instead:

```
["gnuplot", "-e", "set output '${imageFile.toString()}'; filename='${dataFile.toString()}'; ${args}", plotFile.toString()].execute()
```