# Running python script with groovy .execute()

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I've been wracking my head on this one for a while.

I am in an Active Choices Parameter in a jenkins job. I'm executing the following command to run a script through the .execute() function.

```
def output = ("python /home/jenkins/cih.py --run get_info --object ${ Object } ").execute()
```

Now, as is it will operate ask expected when the Object name is a single word. When ran on Object names with multiple words, it fails. I can't retrieve any logs as the script isn't ran. \ "${ Object }\ " similarly fails and in fact won't return single word objects anymore.

Also if i swap to def output = ["python", "/home/jenkins/cih.py", "--run", "get_info", "--object", Object].execute();
Not even the single worded object will work anymore but i understand this is the way to go in this situation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does this curl command fail when executed in groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56707382/why-does-this-curl-command-fail-when-executed-in-groovy) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60957550/groovy-string-not-executing-with-execute-the-same-way-it-does-on-command-line/60957602#60957602 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377884/groovy-execute-works-on-windows-but-fails-on-linux/46388711#46388711 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57005029/postgresql-unterminated-quoted-identifier/57006208#57006208